# Import with react version 5.0.1 cause error

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, react-router-dom

Recently I pulled a new project from github and did all of the procedures as it should be, but upon starting the client I encountered this error message: 'Attempted import error: useHistory is not exported from react-router-dom'. I rechecked the version of react-router-dom package, and it was @5.0.1. If someone is familiar with such an issue, please suggest me some solutions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your react-router-dom version from 5.0.1 to 5.2.0

It will work.

Comment: To OP, uninstall the current version and install the specific 5.2.0 version. From the project directory run `npm un -s react-router-dom; npm i -s react-router-dom@5.2.0`. If you've also `react-router` installed then ensure it's updated to a compatible version as well.